# Multiple selection in Dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am wondering that if an **ASP DropDownList** Control support Multiple Selection or not?
     If Yes, then how can i enabled multiple selection in DropDownList ???

Answer (score 1):

No, but there's lots of free stuff on the web. Here's a full sourcecode, tutorial and example for just what you need:

[Link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/MultiSelectDropdownList.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

By native dropdown never allow multiple selection, but you can use list box instead of that, this have option to set mutli / single item selection. Other wise if you want customized one you have to use some jquery plugin or some other js frame work plugins

you can try this sample link :)

[jQuery Dropdown Check List](http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, then you want to enable the multiple selection in your drop down list.
Here are some references where custom controls can solve your problem:
[Check here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/MultiSelectDropdownList.aspx)
Or [Check here](http://aspnetachives.blogspot.com/2009/03/multiple-selection-dropdownlist-for.html)